# When a Function Component is rendered with a tag, is it treated as an object instance of that function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For example, if a `const num = 1` is declared in a function component, can I refer to it in the `return` statement as `this.num`?

Can function components have static variables like that?

Comment: to access `this.num`, we have to declare it as `this.num = 1`. Using `const`, `var` or `let`, creates a local scoped variables, but they are not present on the instance(this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can declare variables within functional components and refer to them in the return statement like this:

```
function Test() {
    const num = 1
    return num
}
```

Using the "this" keyword will refer to the enclosing object, not the local scope. See [this - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).